# IBM MQ server is down as the disk space is 100%. How to clear this queue?

Tags: server, ibm-mq

IBM MQ manager is down due to 100% disk usage. One of the queue is using 69GB of disk space. How to clear this queue with out corrupting the mq manager. The GUI or command prompt is not working as there is no space left.

```
69G     QA!QM!PSST
```

Comment: You can normally get enough space to start the queue manager by temporarily moving the `AMQERR02.LOG` and `AMQERR03.LOG` out of the queue manager's errors directory. I recommend you start it with no services, channel initiators, listeners by using `strmqm -ns`. You can then clear the queue, stop it, move the logs back and start it normally.

Comment: In this day and age, 69GB is not that much space.  Did you not get an alert from your MQ monitoring tool that the disk space was getting low?  I would get your SysAdmin to allocate at least another 500GB (or 1TB) for your MQ server to use.  Just out of curiosity, what is the average message size?  Or how many messages were on the queue?